# Angular Routing Nested components not working

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, lazy-loading, angular-routing

I'm working in an Angular 10 application and I have some problem to go to nested components in routes loaded by lazy module. The thing is like this:

My app.component has a `<router-outlet>` which can display 2 different components, the `app-layout.component`, and the `auth-layout.component`. App component is only displayed if an auth guard authorize it. If not, then, it will displayed not-found route (also for '**' path)

The layouts has many HTML views that gives options to navigate to another modules, loaded by lazy loading. So app-layout and auth-layout also have their own `<router-outlet>` to show the modules.

Each module has their routing, but for now it only works as a parent a unique base component.

What I need is showing account-config component, put a `<router-outlet>` in and render other components inside ('couse account-config.component has a second navigation bar)

This image ilustrates what I need
[image]

I tried many ways to do it but it seems like I'm doing wrong.

Here's a minimal reproduction in stackblitz ------->>>> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-5nfvke?file=src/app/pages/modules/account-config/components/account-config/account-config.component.html

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to remove  `pathMatch: 'full'` from the path `account-config` in `app-routing.module.ts`

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked!! I put the "pathMatch: 'full'" because I use a canLoad connected with ngrx to maintain the session.